# what is the cause for java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, ftp, socketexception, connection-timeout

I have written a java code to connect FTP.I used `ftp4j-1.7.2` jar to connect FTP through java.I have used String[] "**it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.connect(String arg0)**" and "**it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.disconnect(boolean arg0)**" methods to connect and disconnect from FTP.The code is working fine when i run it in java 1.5 but it's throwing "**java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out**" while disconnecting when i run it in java 1.6.Can anyone please let me know solution for this.

Error Log:

```
Stack:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:107)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:93)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:151)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.NVTASCIIReader.readLine(NVTASCIIReader.java:105)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.read(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:142)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:187)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.disconnect(FTPClient.java:1133)
```

Comment: you are trying to connect and the server is not available or you have wrong url

Comment: No i am successfully able to connect and disconnect when i run the code in java 1.5   and we are able to connect when we run it in java 1.6 but we are unable to just disconnect

Comment: @anfy2002us It is perfectly clear from the stack trace that he is trying to *disconnect,* which implies that his connect succeeded, and therefore that the server *was* available *and* that his URL was correct as well. Do read the question.

Comment: I'm coming here from debugging a JAVA application in which this error is caused by the process running out of heap memory. Might not be the case here, but it's a pointer to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

This could be an IPv issue. Try this flag:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: This is less of an answer, and more of a comment.

Comment: IPv6 issues would cause connection problems, not read timeouts during disconnect. -1

Answer (score 0):

It means no data arrived during the timeout period. In this case no reply to the disconnect request. Clearly the library you are using is setting a read timeout, or maybe you are, and it is too short, see if you can increase it.

I can't account for the different behaviour with different JDKs, unless there was a read timeout fix somewhere, but I've never been aware of any read timeout problems at all, and I go all the way back to 1.1.2.

Comment: But i am able to run it in java 1.5 but facing issue with java 1.6,may i kno what could be the issue.